# Joomla - add last modified date to category

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to add last modified date to category. There are no any options in "Category view options". Or I need to edit the template page?

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities to show the modified date.

1. Global parameters in the article manager
2. In each article
3. In the menu item's options (category blog for example)

No. 3 is most probably the setting your are looking for.

Comment: I have a category for example "cat1", I access it "www.example.com/cat1", there I have a list of items from cat1. Below this list I need to show last modified date of a list.

Comment: I would suggest creating a menu item with a category blog to display the desired category. Then you have a setting there to display the modified date.